# NGRX feature reducers are not initialized in angular9

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have created an angular9 application by using Nrwl Nx and NGRX. I have setup store for both application and feature. The feature is created as library. However while initializing the app.reducer for root store is getting triggered, where as feature reducer is not triggered. Below is the code.

Upon troubleshooting I found below:
1. @ngrx/store/update-reducers has not been triggered.
2. The below warning has been observed in console.

```
@ngrx/store: The feature name "auth" does not exist in the state, therefore createFeatureSelector cannot access it.  Be sure it is imported in a loaded module using StoreModule.forRoot('auth', ...) or StoreModule.forFeature('auth', ...).  If the default state is intended to be undefined, as is the case with router state, this development-only warning message can be ignored.
(anonymous) @ store.js:1110
(anonymous) @ store.js:1015
defaultStateFn @ store.js:1011
(anonymous) @ store.js:1070
memoized @ store.js:976
(anonymous) @ store.js:1015
defaultStateFn @ store.js:1011
(anonymous) @ store.js:1070
memoized @ store.js:976
(anonymous) @ store.js:854
_next @ map.js:29
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_next @ map.js:35
next @ Subscriber.js:49
_subscribe @ ReplaySubject.js:57
_trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
_trySubscribe @ Subject.js:81
subscribe @ Observable.js:28
_subscribe @ Observable.js:76
subscribe @ Observable.js:27
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
_subscribe @ Observable.js:76
subscribe @ Observable.js:27
call @ map.js:16
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
call @ distinctUntilChanged.js:11
subscribe @ Observable.js:23
createSubscription @ common.js:5793
_subscribe @ common.js:5915
transform @ common.js:5892
ɵɵpipeBind1 @ core.js:36749
LoginComponent_Template @ login.component.html:1
executeTemplate @ core.js:12010
refreshView @ core.js:11857
refreshComponent @ core.js:13295
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:11586
refreshView @ core.js:11909
refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews @ core.js:13220
refreshView @ core.js:11880
refreshComponent @ core.js:13295
refreshChildComponents @ core.js:11586
refreshView @ core.js:11909
renderComponentOrTemplate @ core.js:11983
tickRootContext @ core.js:13457
detectChangesInRootView @ core.js:13491
detectChanges @ core.js:15182
tick @ core.js:42908
(anonymous) @ core.js:42758
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
onInvoke @ core.js:41465
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:363
run @ zone-evergreen.js:123
run @ core.js:41240
next @ core.js:42755
schedulerFn @ core.js:36985
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:36947
checkStable @ core.js:41379
onHasTask @ core.js:41486
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:419
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:440
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:263
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:184
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:569
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:552
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:388
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:210
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:230
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:847
then @ zone-evergreen.js:979
bootstrapModule @ core.js:42457
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
Show 39 more frames
```

Please help me to crack the issue.

**app.module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedModule } from '@family-health/shared'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { appReducer, metaReducers, rootInitialState } from './+state/app.reducer';
import { StoreRouterConnectingModule, NavigationActionTiming } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    SharedModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      appReducer,
      { metaReducers, initialState: rootInitialState }
    ),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
      navigationActionTiming: NavigationActionTiming.PostActivation
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.reducer**

```
import { AppBaseActions } from './app.actions';
import { MetaReducer, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import * as fromRouter from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { AuthActionTypes } from '@family-health/auth';

export interface AppBaseData {
    IsSideNavVisible: boolean;
}

export const appBaseInitialState: AppBaseData = {
    IsSideNavVisible: true
}

export const rootInitialState = {
    router: {
      state: {
        url: '/',
        params: {},
        queryParams: {}
      },
      navigationId: 0
    },
  };

  export const appReducer = {
    router: fromRouter.routerReducer, // ActionReducerMap<AppRouterState>
    base: appBaseReducer
  };

export function appBaseReducer(
    state = appBaseInitialState,
    action: AppBaseActions
  ): AppBaseData {
    return state;
}

export function resetStateOnLogout(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return function (state, action) {
    if (action.type === AuthActionTypes.Logout) {
      return reducer(rootInitialState, action);
    }

    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = [resetStateOnLogout, storeFreeze];
```

**auth.module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './containers/login/login.component';
import { Routes as AuthRoutes } from './auth.routes';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './components/login-form/login-form.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@family-health/material';
import { SharedModule } from '@family-health/shared';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { authReducer, initialState as authInitialState } from './+state/auth.reducer';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthEffects } from './+state/auth.effects';

export const sharedAuthRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: AuthRoutes.Login.path, component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: AuthRoutes.Login.path, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModule,
    SharedModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('auth', authReducer, {
      initialState: authInitialState
    }),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects])
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent, LoginFormComponent]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**auth.reducer:**

```
import { AuthActions } from './auth.actions';

export interface AuthData {
    loading: boolean;
}
/**
 * Interface to the part of the Store containing AuthState
 * and other information related to AuthData.
 */
export interface AuthState {
    readonly auth: AuthData;
}

export const initialState: AuthData = {
    loading: false
}

export function authReducer(
    state = initialState,
    action: AuthActions
  ): AuthData {
    switch (action.type) {
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^9.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "9.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
```